# c++ print hex bytes unsigned char LPBYTE to string?

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, byte

I have received and can save the file through my buffer of bytes, but how can I print them out? hex unsigned char.

my new code

```
    unsigned char* _fileBytes;

static char* ReadAllBytes(char const* filename)
{
    ifstream ifs(filename, ios::binary);
    ifs.seekg(0, ifs.end);
    int len = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg(0, ifs.beg);

    char* bytes = new char[len];

    ifs.read(bytes, len);
    ifs.close();

    return bytes;
}
int main(int argc, WCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* gg = ReadAllBytes("C:\\file.txt");
    _fileBytes = (unsigned char*)gg;
    std::cout << std::hex;
    for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(_fileBytes); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2)
            << static_cast<unsigned>(_fileBytes[i]) << ' ';
    }
   getchar();
}
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73487559/edit) your question to show *how* you want to *print* them out. On the way, also define what *print* means in your case: standard output, Windows console, printer?

Comment: You cannot iterate through a pointer with range based for loop. How can the compiler know how many bytes are there? Just use a regular for loop with a condition to check for the end of buffer.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i != size; ++i) and print byte[i] ?

Comment: How many `BYTE`s is `pByte` pointing at? Is `hBytes` an array or another pointer?

Comment: @TedLyngmo check my new code

Comment: @IvanM1999 Ok, I added a separate answer instead of trying to keep up with the edits in Code Gorillas answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `hBytes` is an actual array, you can use a range based `for`-loop on `hBytes` - but not `pByte` like you try to do. A single pointer does not carry information about how many elements that are accessible.

```
std::cout << std::hex;
for (unsigned char byte : hBytes)
{
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2)
              << static_cast<unsigned>(byte) << ' ';
}
```

Comment: You won't see any hex digits unless you cast to a non-`char` type so I updated the answer. Hope you're ok with that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo In this case you could have casted also to `int` by just writing `+byte`, right? Since the value is already unsigned, there is no risk to get negative numbers.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Yes and since `BYTE` is unsigned, one could even have done `for(unsigned byte : myBuffer)` (or `for(int byte ...`) and not have to bother at all.

Comment: check post please

Answer (score 0):

This will not work:

```
for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(_fileBytes); ++i)
```

`_fileBytes` is a `unsigned char*` which has a fixed size (usually 4 or 8). You need the pass the length information back to `main` somehow. In main you could then do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
   // ...
}
```

But, you do not need the raw pointers at all. C++ has a container class created for this, `std::vector`, and it keeps the memory safe as well as storing information about how many elements it contains.

Example assuming that you really need to store the whole file in memory:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::vector<unsigned char> ReadAllBytes(std::filesystem::path filename) {
    std::vector<unsigned char> data;
    // reserve space in the vector for the whole file
    data.reserve(std::filesystem::file_size(filename));

    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    // fill the vector with the content of the whole file using the
    // vector insert member function that takes two iterators:
    data.insert(data.end(), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs),
                            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
    return data;
}
int main() {
    try {
        // `auto gg` is here short for `std::vector<unsigned char> gg = ...`
        auto gg = ReadAllBytes("C:/file.txt");

        std::cout << std::hex;

        for(unsigned value : gg) {
            std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << value << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

The range based `for`-loop is a simplifiation of:

```cpp
    for(auto it = gg.begin(); it != gg.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << *it << ' ';
    }
```

or

```cpp
    for(size_t i = 0; i < gg.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << gg[i] << ' ';
    }
```

---

If you *don't* need to have the whole file in memory, it's much easier. Just read one character at a time:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char ch;
    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt", std::ios::binary);

    std::cout << std::hex;
    while(ifs.get(ch)) {
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2)
                  << static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch))
                  << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @IvanM1999 pictures are of no use. Please use an online compiler, like https://godbolt.org/ if you want to share code

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/KqWfhY51e

Comment: @IvanM1999 I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain what's wrong? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: for any file? I read the .txt file successfully, but the screenshot of 10 mb breaks exe.

Comment: @IvanM1999 It works for much more than 10 MB for me - but there a physical limit depending on your computer. Do you really need the whole file stored in memory? If not, the solution is very simple.

Comment: @IvanM1999 I updated my first example to be more memory friendly - and if that doesn't work, you probably don't have enough memory to read the whole file into memory. I also added an example that doesn't store while file in memory at all, which should work even on systems with very limited memory resources.